# Android getting FileNotFound Exception, even if file exists

Tags: android

As the title suggests I am getting `"FileNotFoundException"` even if image exists in SDCard, and even with all my efforts I am not able to find any reason for it. I have the permission in manifest for writing on external storage. Also this occurs for only certain images, so it's quite complicating the issue.

The path of the image is:  /mnt/sdcard/projFolder/1090901/-23686809809
Following is the code to download image :

```
    URL Url = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConn = Url.openConnection(); 

if(!enoughSpaceLeft(urlConn.getContentLength())){

       onError(NoSpaceError);
     break;
}

    InputStream is = Url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1)
        os.write(b, 0, length);

    os.close();
    is.close();
```

I am attaching the image that is creating problem , it's actually a QR code

[image]

Comment: maybe issues with lowercase/uppercase letters?

Comment: This occurs even with normal BitmapFactory.decode(path);, it returns null..........

Comment: can you put some code, and the "path"

Comment: put your whole code and importantly url (file downloading path) and   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file); (output file path )
completely.

Comment: the reason behind this actually I think if some file contains a space in download url then I think when the image written on sdcard then its not completely available. But if this happen then I think that doesn't give you file not found exception.

Comment: Yes as per my knowledge that will give URLMalformedException.......

Comment: Have you tried to put the image in the resource folder and put it in an imageview? This is just to know whether the image is actually causing the trouble.

Comment: is there all images have name without white space in it on server?

Comment: @blessenm : It is not showing it in imageView also, neither from sdcard nor from assets........

Comment: I just saved ur image and put it in my drawable folder and was able to put it in an imageview.

Comment: @blessenm : kkkkkk I tried with assets......

Answer (score 1):

You should have write-to-SD card permissions.

Comment: he already mentioned it in question "I have the permission in manifest for writing on external storage. "

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that it won't be possible to read from the SD card if the phone is connected to a computer and mass storage mode is on.